# While running Karate(1.0.1) tests from Spock, System property that was set in mock ends up undefined in karate.properties['message']

Tags: karate, spock

In karate version 0.9.5 I was able to use System.setProperty('message', message) during a mock invocation.  Then that property was available inside a feature using karate.properties['message'].  I have upgraded to version 1.0.1 and now result of karate.properties['message'] results in undefined

Spock Test code

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApiTestRunnerSpec extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port

    @SpringBean
    MessageLogger messageLogger = Mock()

    def "setup"() {
        System.out.println("Running on port: " + port)
        System.setProperty("server.port", "" + port)
    }

    def "Run Mock ApiTest"() {
        given:
        System.setProperty('foo', 'bar')

        when:
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5)

        then:
        results != null
        1 * messageLogger.logMessage(_ as String) >> { String message ->
            assert message != null
            System.setProperty("message", message)
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
public class MessageController {

  @Autowired private MessageLogger messageLogger;

  @GetMapping("/message")
  public String message() {
    String message = "Important Message";

    messageLogger.logMessage(message);

    return message;
  }
}
```

MessageLogger

```java
@Component
public class MessageLogger {

  public void logMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

karate-config.js

```js
function fn() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 10000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 10000);
  karate.configure('ssl', true);

  var config = {
    localUrl: 'http://localhost:' + java.lang.System.getProperty('server.port'),
  };
  print('localUrl::::::::::', config.localUrl);
  return config;
}
```

Feature

```
@mockMessage
@parallel=true
Feature: Test Message

  Background:
    * url localUrl

  Scenario: GET

  Given path '/message'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  * print 'foo value ' + karate.properties['foo']
  * print 'message value ' + karate.properties['message']
```

**0.9.5**

```
2021-04-28 15:07:51.819 (...) [print] **foo value bar**
2021-04-28 15:07:51.826 (...) [print] **message value Important Message**
```

**1.0.1**

```
2021-04-28 14:36:58.566 (...) [print] **foo value bar** 
2021-04-28 14:36:58.580 (...) [print] **message value undefined**
```

[Link to project on github](https://github.com/kcrowe123/spock-karate-example)

Comment: I see you accepted my PRs a while ago. Some feedback here and accepting + upvoting my answer in order to close the question would be a nice sign of appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned your project and noticed a few outdated things (Groovy, Spock and GMaven+ versions). Upgrading them did not change the outcome, I can still reproduce your problem.

A also noticed that in your two branches the POM differs in more than just the Karate version number, also the dependencies differ. If I use the ones from the 1.0.1 branch, tests do not work under 0.9.5 anymore. So I forked your project and sent you two pull requests for each branch with a dependency setup working identically for both Karate versions. Now the branches really just differ in the Karate version number:

https://github.com/kriegaex/spock-karate-example/compare/karate-0.9.5...kriegaex:karate-1.0.1

BTW, for some reason I had to compile your code running JDK 11, JDK 16 did not work. GMaven+ complained about Java 16 groovy class files (bytecode version 60.0), even though GMaven+ should have used target level 11. No idea what this is about. Anyway, on Java 11 I can reproduce your problem. As the Spock version is identical for both branches, I guess the problem is within Karate itself. I recommend to open an issue there, linking to your GitHub project (after you have accepted my PRs). Spock definitely sets the system property, I have added more log output into the stubbing closure order to verify that. Maybe this is an issue concerning how and when Karate communicates with Spock.

---

**Update:** Peter Thomas suggested in his answer to store the value to be transferred to the feature in a Java object and access that one from the feature after the Spock test has set it. I guess, he means something like this:

https://github.com/kriegaex/spock-karate-example/commit/ca88e3da

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApiTestRunnerSpec extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port

    @SpringBean
    MessageLogger messageLogger = Mock() {
        1 * logMessage(_ as String) >> { String message ->
            assert message != null
            MessageHolder.INSTANCE.message = message
        }
    }

    def "setup"() {
        System.out.println("Running on port: " + port)
        System.setProperty("server.port", "" + port)
    }

    def "Run Mock ApiTest"() {
        given:
        Results results = Runner
          .path("classpath:")
          .systemProperty("foo", "bar")
          .tags("~@ignore")
          .parallel(5)

        expect:
        results
    }
    
    static class MessageHolder {
        public static final MessageHolder INSTANCE = new MessageHolder()
        private String message

        private MessageHolder() {}

        String getMessage() {
            return message
        }

        void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message
        }
    }
}
```

```
@mockMessage
@parallel=true
Feature: Test Message

  Background:
    * url localUrl

  Scenario: GET

  Given path '/message'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  * print 'foo value ' + karate.properties['foo']
  * def getMessage =
    """
    function() {
      var MessageHolder = Java.type('com.example.spock.karate.ApiTestRunnerSpec.MessageHolder');
      return MessageHolder.INSTANCE.getMessage();
    }
    """
  * def message = call getMessage {}
  * print 'message value ' + message
```

---

**Update 2:** This is the implementation of Peter's second idea to simply access Java system properties via JS. So I simplified the working, but unnecessarily complicated version with the message holder singleton, eliminating it again:

https://github.com/kriegaex/spock-karate-example/commit/e235dd71

Now it simply looks like this (similar to the original Spock specification, only refactored to be a bit less verbose):

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApiTestRunnerSpec extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port

    @SpringBean
    MessageLogger messageLogger = Mock() {
        1 * logMessage(_ as String) >> { String message ->
            assert message != null
            System.setProperty('message', message)
        }
    }

    def "setup"() {
        System.out.println("Running on port: " + port)
        System.setProperty("server.port", "" + port)
    }

    def "Run Mock ApiTest"() {
        expect:
        Runner.path("classpath:").systemProperty("foo", "bar").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5)
    }
}
```

The only important change is in the Karate feature:

```
@mockMessage
@parallel=true
Feature: Test Message

  Background:
    * url localUrl

  Scenario: GET

  Given path '/message'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  * print 'foo value ' + karate.properties['foo']
  * def getMessage = function() { return Java.type('java.lang.System').getProperty('message'); }
  * print 'message value ' + getMessage()
```

Comment: we made karate "safer" that properties at the time of suite start are locked. the best way forward is as `kriegaex` said above, give us a way to replicate. and make sure you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but first please try the `Runner` builder has a `.systemProperty()` method: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#improved-test-suite-builder

Comment: @PeterThomas, just clone [my fork](https://github.com/kriegaex/spock-karate-example) and compare the behaviour in branches _karate-0.9.5_ vs. _karate-1.0.1_. Just make sure to compile using JDK 11, something seems to be off with the GMaven+ configuration in the sample project.

Comment: ok. I hope it is a minimal / simple example.

Comment: Simple enough IMO. I got it running quickly. It involves Spring Boot, though. But you won't have problems, I guess.

Comment: **Update:** @PeterThomas, do you mean something like I did according to your advice in my updated answer? It works as expected, even though - disclaimer - it was my first try with Karate, it is quick & dirty and not thread-safe if multiple threads would use the `MessageHolder` concurrently. Then something like a `ThreadLocal<String> message` would be better.

Comment: yes. also see my answer edit. `java.lang.System.getProperty('foo')` may be more than sufficient, struck me a little late

Comment: great :) and since you haven't heard of karate before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364489/143475

Comment: @kriegaex - Thank you so much for taking the time to clean up my branches and isolating the problem as well as offering several solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `Runner` "builder" has a `.systemProperty()` method which is recommended.

Please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#improved-test-suite-builder

So this should work. Else as I said in the comments, please submit a way to replicate.

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:")
    .systemProperty("foo", "bar")
    .tags("~@ignore").parallel(5)
```

EDIT: so I can confirm that `karate.properties` is made immutable at the time the test-suite starts.

So here are the 3 options:

- change your test strategy so that all dynamic params are resolved before you start
- instead of `karate.properties[]` do the old-school `java.lang.System.getProperty('foo')` call in Karate / JS, I'm pretty sure that will work
- use a Java singleton to hold shared state for your test-runner and karate-feature

Comment: Well, that does not solve the OP's problem. He wants to set the second property while the Runner is already doing something, from within the mock's stubbed method. This looks ugly, but it seems to have worked in 0.9.5. Sorry, this is the very first time I ever heard of Karate, I am just a Spock user. How can the OP set a property value later or otherwise communicate the message to the print method in the Karate feature?

Comment: @kriegaex ah. yes that's not possible any more in karate 1.X and I can confirm that. so my recommendation is to change the test approach or write a java singleton that is responsible for holding this "state". it is pretty easy to access any java class from karate and call methods on it. here everything is going to be in the same jvm for sure - so I edited my answer, see the second option